# How Can I Schedule A Task In Task Scheduler To Run At Startup Every 2 Days?

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7, scheduled-tasks

I've prepared a Bat file that I want to run at startup, but every 2 days.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MichaelS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3510480/michaels)'s solution is sensible. Windows doesn't always provide the tools you need to get things done. In that case, you have to do some of the work yourself.

One idea is to schedule the script to run at startup and then have the script itself decide whether or not it's been "two days" (this measurement is a little ambiguous).

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

IF EXIST lastrun.xml (
   PowerShell.exe -NoProfile -Command "Exit(([Int64](Get-Date).ToOADate() - (Import-CliXML lastrun.xml)) -ge 2)"
   IF "!ERRORLEVEL!"=="0" (
      @ECHO Last run less than two days ago.
      EXIT /B 0
   )
)
@ECHO Last run at least two days ago.

REM   do startup stuff

PowerShell.exe -NoProfile -Command "[Int64](Get-Date).ToOADate()|Export-CliXML lastrun.xml"
```

This script uses PowerShell to save the current date in a file when it gets past the "has it been two days since I last run" check. The date is converted to a 64-bit integer<sup>1</sup>  and exported to a file.<sup>2</sup>

The first thing the script does is check to see how long it's been since it was last run. It subtracts the last run date and compares it to 2. This has the effect of making the script run *any time* during the second day after it was last run. I'm only guessing, but this sounded like what you'd want, based on your description.

Your definition of "run every two days" may necessitate changing the PowerShell code to do more precisely what you want. If you want an exact minimum number of seconds or hours, you can switch from using `ToOADate()` to exporting the DateTime object. When you find the difference, use one of the `TotalHours()` or `TotalMinutes()` methods of the TimeSpan object to give you a more precise number for the amount of time since it was last run.

**UPDATE** (based on question refinements)

This version of the script uses PowerShell to determine how many days ago a defrag was done.
If it was run the same calendar day, do nothing. If it was run one day ago, do a cleanup. If it was run 2 or more calendar days ago, defrag again (and update the time the last defrag was done).
When a cleanup is done, a marker file (to indicate so) is created. If a defrag was done 1 day ago and the marker file already exists, no cleanup will be done.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION


SET "DO_TASK=defrag"
SET "LAST=lastrun.xml"
SET "CLEANUP_MARKER=cleanup.finished"

IF EXIST "%LAST%" (
   PowerShell.exe -NoProfile -Command "Exit(([Int64](Get-Date).ToOADate() - (Import-CliXML !LAST!)))"
   IF "!ERRORLEVEL!"=="0" (
      @ECHO Last defrag was today.
      EXIT /B 0
   ) ELSE IF "!ERRORLEVEL!"=="1" (
      @ECHO Last defrag was yesterday.
      IF NOT EXIST "%CLEANUP_MARKER%" (
         SET "DO_TASK=cleanup"
      ) ELSE (
         @ECHO Cleanup was run today.
         EXIT /B
      )
   ) ELSE (
      @ECHO Last defrag was at least two days ago.
      SET "DO_TASK=defrag"
   )
)

IF "%DO_TASK%"=="cleanup" (

   REM   Cleanup commands
   @ECHO CLEANUP

   @ECHO.>"%CLEANUP_MARKER%"

) ELSE IF "%DO_TASK%"=="defrag" (

   REM   Defrag commands
   @ECHO DEFRAG

   PowerShell.exe -NoProfile -Command "[Int64](Get-Date).ToOADate()|Export-CliXML !LAST!"
   DEL /Q "%CLEANUP_MARKER%"
)
```

---

<sup>1</sup> the number of days since Jan 1, 1900, I think

<sup>2</sup> This may be overkill for an integer, but I originally wrote the script to work with DateTime objects—which, depending on your definition of "two days" may be necessary to use—and the Export-CliXml will work with both.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding this properly. So after "do startup stuff" line, I would put my codes, and in task scheduler run this script at startup, if the script was last run 2 days ago it would execute my codes if not the script would exit? or I'm misunderstanding something?

Comment: @Giancarlo You'd put whatever commands you wish to run around the "do startup stuff." The way it currently behaves, if the script was run less than 2 calendar days ago, it will exit without running any of the "do startup stuff." Otherwise, it will run the "do startup stuff."

Comment: oh good, thats what I wanted. Could you help me with one last addition. So In my example I would run a defrag script every 2 days and the other 2 days cleanup script. So one day its defrag the other day its cleanup and so on (repeating all the time).

Comment: @Giancarlo What should it do if the machine last ran a defrag 3+ days ago but has been off since then? Should it defrag on startup (>2 days) or run the cleanup because the defrag was the last thing done?

Comment: example: Monday - defrag; tuesday - cleanup; wednesday - defrag; thursday - cleanup; and so on. srry for my lame descriptions

Comment: Your example didn't address the scenario I asked about. Do you not care how long it's been and just want to run the two separate tasks on MWF and TR, respectively?

Comment: After defrag is complete and is off, the next day on startup script checks if its been more than 2 days since defrag was run, if not, run my cleanup code, if yes, run defrag again. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: I would like to run those codes on that same script that you provided for me, if that's what you wanted to hear from me. Really appreciate if you could help me here.

Comment: I ran the updated script with my codes (just opened a batch file) and it closed immediately, the message was "was unexpected at this time" before word "was" was some symbol that I couldn't catch my eye on, I did put the "pause" at the end of the whole script though.

Comment: "" was unexpected at this time.

Comment: @Giancarlo Fixed, sorry. I typed "EXISTS" instead of "EXIST"

Comment: This is getting weird, I ran the script, everything went normal, then I checked my Script folder where I had put this script and other files, and there was only one file left!! "!LAST!" (without quotation marks) with the extension of (FILE) what is going on here? fortunetely I was able to restore previous version of folder. I did not turn off my PC for night though, for some reasons, if that's in some way affected the script.

Comment: @Giancarlo `!LAST!` is the variable containing the "last run defrag" date. I don't know why you're seeing that. Ensure that `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` occurs before any of the code in my answer (I have that statement there, too.) Try running the script without any destructive commands (e.g. instead of the commands themselves, echo "defrag", "cleanup", or "nothing" to some file) to verify that it is behaving correctly.

Comment: If you can please check my script: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9y8ylhe9rpoRjI3Z2lTRzhudzA/view?usp=sharing what exactly is my script is that actually everyday is cleaning, but every other day defrag is included

Comment: @Giancarlo I suggest you put all the code for defrag in one script, all the code for cleanup in another, then call those two scripts from a third script (the code in my solution). This will allow you to keep the code sensible instead of heavily modding it to use it inside a `(...)` (see my comment below).

Comment: The first problem I see is that you defining variables inside a `( ... )` block, but attempting to access them as `%dump_path%`. This won't work. Sadly, the entire `(...)` expression is evaluated, including `%dump_path%` all at once, before any of the `set` commands takes place. This in __extremely__ counterintuitive, but that's CMD for you. Delayed Expansion allows you to access variables set "in the middle" of statement execution, and use the bang (`!`) instead of percent (`%`). So, instead of accessing a var `%dump_path%`, use `!dump_path!`.

Comment: starting 2 scripts from third appears to be working fine now, just one minor problem though, cleanup finished, but cmd window didn't close, what line should I add to close it automatically?.</br> `REM   Cleanup commands
   @ECHO CLEANUP
START Cleanup1.bat`

Comment: I have no pause in any of those two scripts

Comment: `EXIT /B` will exit a running script (or subroutine call). I also suggest invoking the sub-scripts (defrag and cleanup) by invoking the shell, like `CMD /C %~dp0defrag.cmd`. Depending on how you invoke them, the execution may never return to the caller. I wish I could point you to some good documentation, but there isn't anything from MS. [SS64](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html) might be as close as it gets.

Comment: So maybe `START /WAIT Cleanup1.bat` and next line `EXIT /B` ?

Answer (score 2):

Have you even tried something? Just open the Windows Task Scheduler, right-click to your task library, select `Create Task...`, set the desired options, click `Triggers`, click `New`, select `Daily` and type a `2` in the `Recur every: ___ days`. Afterwards add your bat file to the task in the `Actions` dialogue. That's it.

Comment: This won't run it at startup, will it?

Comment: Just take a look at the options of the scheduler. You can tell it to work as you whish. Run on startup if the scheduled point in time is over or even wake your computer to run the task at the scheduled time.

Comment: I can create a task to reccur every 2 days at scheduled time, but I can not schedule a task every 2 days at startup...

Comment: In the advanced settings you can select how the task should behave if the scheduled run was not started at the selected time. One of the options is to run it at the next possible moment. So if your PC was turned off and you turning it on (= start up) the task will be started if the last run is more than 2 days ago.